# Evaluation of the surface integral $\iint_S z^2 dS$ where S is part of the parabaloid $x = y^2 + z^2$ given by $0 \le x \le 1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, surface-integrals

we have

$\iint_S z^2 dS$ , where $S$ is $x = y^2 + z^2$ for $0 \le x \le 1$

i have already simplified the integral using correct parameterizations and have

$1)$ $\iint_S z^2 dS$ $=$ $\iint_S z^2\sqrt{1+4(y^2 + z^2)}dS$

To further simplify the integral i will convert using polar coordinates $y=rcos\theta$ , $z=rsin\theta$ which simplifies to

$2)$ $\iint_D r^2sin^2\theta \sqrt{1 + 4r^2} r dA$

This is where i am stuck, i know everything up to $1)$ is correct. but it looks like converting to polar coordinates makes the integral more difficult. So my question is how to solve integral 1)
**thanks**

Comment: The $dS$ on the right-hand side of 1) should be $dA$, and the integral should no longer be over $S$. It should be over $D$.

Answer (score 1):

When I first learnt how to do surface integrals it was always helpful to draw the surface.

If you struggle to visualize a surface then a good way to understand the shape is to draw it in 4 parts 
-> the surface in the x-y plane, with z=0
-> the surface in the x-z plane, with y=0
-> the surface in the y-z plane, with x=0 
-> and finally the 3D surface in the x-y-z plane if it would help you understand the calculation

Normally you would take the equation you are given for the surface and rewrite it in the form z=f(x,y) because dA=dxdy

Then in the surface integral you substitute f(x,y) in place of z and the bounds are given by the values or graphs for x and y

In your case you are given the bounds for x, 0 and 1. Typically the bounds of either x or y will be given as constants and from there you set the bounds for the other variable in terms of the variable that you were given then constants for 
-> e.g. since you were given the bounds of x as constants, your bounds of y may be written as y=some function involving x, and then you integrate in terms of y first, then in terms of x.

After you’ve correctly substituted it becomes easier with practice to tell if converting to polar coordinates would be helpful or not.

I hope that this is maybe helpful somehow...

Comment: Sorry but not really, up to 1) i know that the integrand is correct, however my problem lies in actually solving the double integral after we have it set up. Since we are dealing w a changing circular region polar coordinates seems like the way to go, but it makes the integral even harder to work with, so my question is how to go about solving integral 1)

Answer (score 0):

Actually your polar integral in 2 is correct. While the integral itself is difficult to solve you can use something like Wolframalpha and it will solve it with no problems.

For the two integrals, the inner integral goes from 0 to the r (radius) and the outer integral goes from 0 to 2pi.

The result is a constant times pi and that is the answer. So everything that you did was correct its just a hard integral to solve.